# Protobuf-net v3 DateTimeOffset Surrogate

Tags: .net-core, protobuf-net

I've seen some other SO's where people are using DateTimeOffset surrogates to handle deserializing those properties, however when I try to copy those, I continue to get a `System.InvalidOperationException: No serializer defined for type: System.DateTimeOffset` error.

```cs
[ProtoContract]
public TestClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public DateTimeOffset Time { get; set; }
}
```

Surrogate class

```cs
[ProtoContract]
public class DateTimeOffsetSurrogate
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public long DateTimeTicks { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public short OffsetMinutes { get; set; }
    
    public static implicit operator DateTimeOffsetSurrogate(DateTimeOffset value)
    {
        return new DateTimeOffsetSurrogate
        {
            DateTimeTicks = value.Ticks,
            OffsetMinutes = (short)value.Offset.TotalMinutes
        };
     }
    
     public static implicit operator DateTimeOffset(DateTimeOffsetSurrogate value)
     {
         return new DateTimeOffset(value.DateTimeTicks, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(value.OffsetMinutes));
     }
}
```

Then I'm registering it right before the http call. I've tried moving this registration into a few different places but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Did this change in v3 or something or am I doing something wrong? Sorry - new to protobuf-net :)

```cs
public async Task<Response<IEnumerable<TestClass>>> GetData()
{
    RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(DateTimeOffset), false).SetSurrogate(typeof(DateTimeOffsetSurrogate));
    
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "my-url");
                    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-protobuf"));

    var result = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        
    var items= ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<Response<IEnumerable<TestClass>>>(await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
                    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using version 3.1.22 (Currently the latest) of protobuf-net right now with the following setup.

```cs
// Needs to be only called at application startup, e.g. in the Startup.cs calls of your web API.
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(DateTimeOffset), false).SetSurrogate(typeof(DateTimeOffsetSurrogate));
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(DateTimeOffset?), false).SetSurrogate(typeof(DateTimeOffsetSurrogate));
```

The surrogate handler I use successfully, can be found below. No black magic happening here, just serializing / deserializing the unix timestamp to long and vice versa:

```cs
namespace Something
{
    using System;
    using ProtoBuf;

    /// <summary>
    /// A surrogate handler for the <see cref="DateTimeOffset"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    [ProtoContract(Name = nameof(DateTimeOffset))]
    public class DateTimeOffsetSurrogate
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the value.
        /// </summary>
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public long? Value { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the <see cref="DateTimeOffsetSurrogate"/> to a <see cref="DateTimeOffset"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="surrogate">The surrogate handler.</param>
        public static implicit operator DateTimeOffset(DateTimeOffsetSurrogate surrogate)
        {
            if (surrogate?.Value is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(surrogate));
            }

            var dt = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(surrogate.Value.Value);
            dt = dt.ToLocalTime();
            return dt;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the <see cref="DateTimeOffsetSurrogate"/> to a <see cref="DateTimeOffset"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="surrogate">The surrogate handler.</param>
        public static implicit operator DateTimeOffset?(DateTimeOffsetSurrogate? surrogate)
        {
            if (surrogate?.Value is null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var dt = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(surrogate.Value.Value);
            dt = dt.ToLocalTime();
            return dt;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the <see cref="DateTimeOffset"/> to a <see cref="DateTimeOffsetSurrogate"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">The source.</param>
        public static implicit operator DateTimeOffsetSurrogate(DateTimeOffset source)
        {
            return new DateTimeOffsetSurrogate
            {
                Value = source.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the <see cref="DateTimeOffset"/> to a <see cref="DateTimeOffsetSurrogate"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">The source.</param>
        public static implicit operator DateTimeOffsetSurrogate(DateTimeOffset? source)
        {
            return new DateTimeOffsetSurrogate
            {
                Value = source?.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe, you want to give it a try. Maybe `[ProtoContract(Name = nameof(DateTimeOffset))]` is what you're missing, but I'm not sure.